# How to add users programmatically to wso2 key manager?

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using wso2 API Manager with the default key manager. I'm not using Identity Server (IS) in the setup.

I have read that Identity Server (IS) provides [SCIM Apis](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/SCIM+APIs) to add users programmatically. Is it possible to do the same, without IS?

I would expect that
1) an application should be able to register a new user (with username and password) to Key Manager
2) the application should call the /token service in order to get the token, using username, password and Basic Authentication with the API key I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

From your request I assume you are using WSO2 APIM (you may be specific in your questions)

> I have read that Identity Server (IS) provides SCIM Apis to add users programmatically. Is it possible without IS?

As far I know the SCIM is provided by an identity server (short answer - no), but there are other options you may have to achieve your goals

> I would expect that 1) an application should be able to register a new user (with username and password)  to Key Manager

1. You could manage users with underlying userstore (LDAP, ...)
2. You can use [Admin Services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/WSO2+Admin+Services), see e.g. RemoteUserStoreManagerService (I'd recommend this option if you are using the build-in jdbc userstore)

> 2) the application should call the /token service in order to get the token, using username, password and Basic Authentication with the API key I have provided.

To get a user token with user credentials you may use [OAuth2 password grant type](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Password+Grant).

IMHO - instead of sending application credentials as basic authentication I suggest to follow pure OAuth2 specification and send the application credentials as parameters (client_id, client_secret). WSO2 supports this option too and this way you stay more aligned to standards (supporting other products/services if needed).